# How to show more than one xml data in html

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to do what W3schools has in this example : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_app_first

But in this example it only shows one CD. I would like to display all the the data (in this case CDs) in the xml file.

This is the code that they have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
i=0;

function displayCD()
{
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br>Title: " + title + "<br>Year: "+ year;
document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD()">

<div id='showCD'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Seems awfully similar to a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30294063/290085) asked nearly simultaneously.

Comment: kjhughes what question???

Comment: The link I left on 'question' went to a nearly identical query, but it's since been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

function displayCD()
{
    for (var i=0; i<x.length;i++) {
        artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br>Title: " + title + "<br>Year: "+ year;
        document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML+=(txt+"<hr/>");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD()">

<div id='showCD'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, is there a way to show each CD in a different DIV ?

Comment: @Silvershark1 yes, just wrap "txt" variable with <div>